# Smaller Labels with Graphics

Tags: labeling

I have two question regarding `Graphics`:

1) How can I make the curve label "Marginal Cost with Externality" to seem smaller? `Imagesize` seems not working!

2) How can I expand the area around the plot so that the label like "Marginal Cost with Externality" is not cut off?

```
gamma2 = .265; z2 = 32000/1000 ;; zbar2 = 46200/1000;
zbar1 = 138100/1000
g2 = 0.44;


Cost4 = g2 zbar2 - g2 a p2 zbar2 gamma2 (1/(1 - τ1));
Gain4 = (zbar2) - zbar2 gamma2 (τ1/(1 - τ1));


d4 = Show[Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost4, {a, {0, 0.1, 0.9}}], {τ1, -1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 50}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Optimal Tax \n Rate", ""}], 
  Graphics[Text["Marginal Cost", {0.85, 22}]] , 
  Graphics[Text["Marginal Cost \n with Externality", {1, 5}], ImageSize -> Tiny]]
```

Comment: Hossein, I just checked your profile: you have been a member for more than 2 years with 15 questions and **0 votes and 0 accepts**.  Please read Michael's welcome message in a comment to [your first question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72086/125) .

Comment: For question 2, why not change the position of the text to `{0.85, 5}`, which prevents cut-off and also makes it line up with the other text.